# Erro idioma selecionado

Tags: c, visual-studio

Copiei um código fonte feito no programa Code Blocks e colei ele em um projeto no Visual Studio C 2010 Express, compilei e está dando alguns erros, um dos erros é nessa linha:

```
int main(){

// Altera a linguagem do console para permitir acentos
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese"); //Erro
```

erro:`Error 2   error C3861: 'setlocale': identifier not found`

Answer (score 1):

Coloquei essa declaração e o erro sumiu.

```
#include <clocale>
```

Concordam?

Comment: Sim. `setlocale` é uma função nativa do C presente na biblioteca `locale`. Você precisará fazer o include da mesma, tal como colocou nesta resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Assim como citado pelo usuário, o problema pode ser resolvido com o include de clocale:

`#include <clocale>`

Comment: Então eu adicionei essa linha no cabeçalho e sumiu o erro: `#include <clocale>` essa é uma boa prática?

Comment: Adicionei essa linha que você deu como resposta e retirei o `#include <clocale>` e o erro apareceu novamente, creio que é falta do `include`.